# Interrupt optim and retrieve the last set of parameters tested

Tags: r

I want to use optim to minimize a function but it takes quite long to converge. Thus, I want to interrupt optim when I see the parameters it plugs in are stuck around some numbers. I wonder if I can keep track of both the function value and the parameters along the way. I can only see the function values when I set control(list(trace=TRUE)).

Please see a replicable example (much simpler than what I have to work on) as below:

`g <- function(x){x[1]^2+x[2]^2}`

`optim(par=c(1,1), g, control = list(trace=TRUE))`

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add an `on.exit` which saves the information.  Before running `optim` set `.optim` to NULL to ensure that we are not looking at an `.optim` from a prior run.

```
g <- function(x) { 
  on.exit(.optim <<- list(x = x, obj = print(returnValue())))
  x[1]^2+x[2]^2 
}

.optim <- NULL
optim(par = c(1, 1), g, control = list(trace = TRUE))
```

giving:

```
  Nelder-Mead direct search function minimizer
[1] 2
function value for initial parameters = 2.000000
  Scaled convergence tolerance is 2.98023e-08
Stepsize computed as 0.100000
[1] 2.21
[1] 2.21
BUILD              3 2.210000 2.000000
[1] 2.02
[1] 2.058125
LO-REDUCTION       5 2.210000 2.000000
[1] 1.81
[1] 1.625
EXTENSION          7 2.020000 1.625000
[1] 1.625
[1] 1.711562
LO-REDUCTION       9 2.000000 1.625000
[1] 1.28
[1] 0.98
EXTENSION         11 1.625000 0.980000
[1] 1
[1] 1.132812
LO-REDUCTION      13 1.625000 0.980000
[1] 0.505
[1] 0.185
EXTENSION         15 1.000000 0.185000
[1] 0.185
[1] 0.3203125
LO-REDUCTION      17 0.980000 0.185000
[1] 0.02
[1] 0.5
REFLECTION        19 0.185000 0.020000
[1] 0.04
[1] 0.0078125
LO-REDUCTION      21 0.185000 0.007813
[1] 0.3203125
[1] 0.03455078
HI-REDUCTION      23 0.034551 0.007813
[1] 0.102207
[1] 0.005395508
HI-REDUCTION      25 0.020000 0.005396
[1] 0.05719238
[1] 0.004512024
HI-REDUCTION      27 0.007813 0.004512
[1] 2.716064e-05
[1] 0.002380447
REFLECTION        29 0.005396 0.000027
[1] 0.01355591
[1] 0.00123909
HI-REDUCTION      31 0.004512 0.000027
[1] 0.004123611
[1] 0.001166844
LO-REDUCTION      33 0.001239 0.000027
[1] 0.001268125
[1] 0.0004683784
HI-REDUCTION      35 0.001167 0.000027
[1] 0.0007208946
[1] 0.0001780652
LO-REDUCTION      37 0.000468 0.000027
[1] 0.0009161481
[1] 0.0001085663
HI-REDUCTION      39 0.000178 0.000027
[1] 7.815627e-05
[1] 1.762216e-05
LO-REDUCTION      41 0.000109 0.000018
[1] 0.0001409279
[1] 2.349272e-05
HI-REDUCTION      43 0.000027 0.000018
[1] 0.0001703958
[1] 8.496039e-07
HI-REDUCTION      45 0.000023 0.000001
[1] 1.338207e-05
[1] 4.260709e-06
LO-REDUCTION      47 0.000018 0.000001
[1] 1.625014e-05
[1] 4.21486e-06
LO-REDUCTION      49 0.000004 0.000001
[1] 1.599159e-05
[1] 9.538017e-07
HI-REDUCTION      51 0.000004 0.000001
[1] 1.042423e-06
[1] 6.601059e-08
LO-REDUCTION      53 0.000001 0.000000
[1] 2.402063e-06
[1] 1.632133e-07
HI-REDUCTION      55 0.000001 0.000000
[1] 1.322682e-06
[1] 1.711765e-07
HI-REDUCTION      57 0.000000 0.000000
[1] 4.077154e-07
[1] 3.113701e-08
HI-REDUCTION      59 0.000000 0.000000
[1] 2.398648e-07
[1] 3.284831e-08
HI-REDUCTION      61 0.000000 0.000000
[1] 3.007464e-07
[1] 4.091568e-09
Exiting from Nelder Mead minimizer
    63 function evaluations used
$par
[1] 3.754010e-05 5.179101e-05

$value
[1] 4.091568e-09

$counts
function gradient 
      63       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

and we can look at the last value of .optim which in this case is the return value from optim but might not be if it were stopped early.

```
> .optim
$x
[1] 3.754010e-05 5.179101e-05

$obj
[1] 4.091568e-09
```